# How to get servlet action (request parameters) from index.html

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have in index.html:

```
<li><a href="list?action=list">List</a></li>
```

and in servlet class

```java
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("List")){
          // do something.....
         }
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.proj.top.web.Servlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/list</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

action in servlet is null.

How can I send this parameter from `index.html` to servlet?

Comment: please show your `web.xml`. I guess there is some misunderstanding about URL-mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't name a servlet "Servlet" for test purposes. May be, somewhere in the big world there exists a base class with the same name...

So I call it "SimpleServlet".

Then you have this `web.xml` (be aware of the fully qualified class name):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>simpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.so.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>simpleServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/list</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, if you call
`http://localhost:8080/simpleServlet/list?action=demo` ,
the variable `action` in `doGet()` will contain "demo"

Also, I suggest to check `action` for null before calling a method on it:

```java
    String action = req.getParameter("action");
    if (action != null)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
```

Comment: Yes it's exactly what i do, but i want send action from index.html.
Thank you.

Comment: please copy the URL belonging to `List` from `index.html` (as displayed in your browser, not HTML source), to your question. Which is the path to your  servlet after deploying?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/top/list?action=list, now it works

<li><a href="list?action=list">List</a></li>

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like that the url mapped to the Servlet with `<url-pattern>` in web.xml is different from what you are using in the `href` attribute of `<a/>` element in the index.html. After changing that url mapping to the consistent one, the code should work.

You can add this value to the `href` attribute to work seamlessly if you use a JSP page instead of simple html page. This will dynamically add the context path of the application to the url and will prevent you from statically typing your context path name.

```
<%= request.getContextPath() %>/list?action=list
```

Comment: No it's the same. I've added web.xml